# Acer monitor serial number

Tags: windows, python-3.x, inventory, edid

I'm tryin to get the serial number of an Acer monitor looking into the windows registry.
I'm parsing the registry with this code in Python 3:

```
import winreg
from winreg import HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

subKey = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY"
k = winreg.OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey)

with winreg.OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey) as k:
    """"
        Open the key 'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY'
        to get the info of all connected monitors
    """
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            with winreg.OpenKey(k, winreg.EnumKey(k, i)) as sk:
                j = 0
                while True:
                    try:
                        with winreg.OpenKey(sk, winreg.EnumKey(sk, j)) as ssk:
                            l = 0
                            while True:
                                try:
                                    if (winreg.EnumKey(ssk, l) == "Control"):
                                        try:
                                            with winreg.OpenKey(ssk, "Device Parameters") as sssk:
                                                strEDID = str(winreg.EnumValue(sssk, 0)[1])
                                                try:
                                                    modelo = strEDID[strEDID.index("\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xfc") + len("\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xfc\\x00"):].split("\\")[0]
                                                    serie = strEDID[strEDID.index("\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xff") + len("\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xff\\x00"):].split("\\")[0]
                                                except:
                                                    modelo = "Not Found"
                                                    serie = "Not Found"

                                                print ("Modelo:", modelo)
                                                print ("Serie:", serie, "\n")

                                                fo = open("salTest.txt", "a")
                                                fo.write(modelo + "\n")
                                                fo.write(serie + "\n\n")
                                                fo.close()

                                        except OSError:
                                            print ("Error")
                                        break
                                    else:
                                        l += 1
                                except OSError:
                                    break
                        j += 1
                    except OSError:
                        break
            i += 1
        except OSError:
            break
```

As result i get an output in the cmd window like this:

```
Modelo: AL1716
Serie: L4802017396L
```

The problem is that the "Serie" isn't the real serial number (an Acer monitor serial number have 22 characters and looks like "ETL480201781700F4B396L")
There is a way to build the real serial number with the "Serie" and the SNID that identify the monitor too.
Here is an example of two Acer monitors:

```
S/N ORIGINAL:           ETL48020178170 (0F4B)396L   |       # ETL480201781700F4B396L
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SNID:                             8170 (0F4B)=03915 |   39  # 81700391539
S/N FROM SCRIPT:          L4802017           396L   |       # L4802017396L



S/N ORIGINAL:           ETL48020178170 (2C98)396L   |       # ETL480201781702C98396L
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SNID:                             8170 (2C98)=11416 |   39  # 81701141639
S/N FROM SCRIPT:          L4802017           396L   |       # L4802017396L
```

Anyone know how to get this info?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just look at the back of the monitor? I don't know that there's any valid reason Windows would import the serial number of every piece of hardware (assuming it's even accessible and valid) and store it in the registry. Although the same thing could be said for a lot of things Windows does, I guess...

Comment: @twalberg - I suspect the OP works as an IT department of an enterprise. Enterprises like to track as much hardware as they can via administration scripts.

Comment: As @selbie says, i need to collect the hardware info from many computers over the network... This problem with Acer monitors is the only problem i have at this moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acer provides the serial number after the `000000ff00` flag but the middle part of the serial number is hidden earlier in the EDID string.

So for example our EDID string looks like this:

> 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

The serial number we want is this:
`LXVSA0013360FEC48510`

The first 8 characters of the serial number `LXVSA001` is encoded as a hex string immediately after the '000000ff00' flag.

The last 4 characters of the serial number `8510` is encoded as a hex string after this first 8 characters.

```
000000ff00 4c|58|56|53|41|30|30|31|38|35|31|30|0a|        <-- EDID (hex)
           L  X  V  S  A  O  0  1  8  5  1  0 (linefeed)  <-- ascii
          (^^^^ first part ^^^^^^)(last part)
```

Now the tricky middle part `3360fec4` is encoded as 4 strings earlier in the EDID.

`33` is at position 30 
`60` is at position 28
`fe` is at position 26
`c4` is at position 24

```
00ffffffffffff0004723a03
position 24 -> c4
position 26 -> fe
position 28 -> 60
position 30 -> 33
24170103682f1e78ca9265a655559f etc
```

When I say 'position' I mean take the EDID string as an array and index from 0.
They are hard to find because they are in reverse order.

In your example, the missing parts of your serial number `81700F4B` should be located as 4 separate 2 character strings at locations 30, 28, 26, and 24 of your idid string.  I can't test that because I don't have the full IDID.

Comment: It totally worked... [Here](http://pastebin.com/4NyuQkTb) is the complete code, if you want to see it... Thx!!!!!!